# c# readonly DataGridView with one enabled cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, controls

I have readonly datagridview, I need in some specific case enable one cell after doubleclicking row (make readonly=false and make focus on this specific cell in current row (like entering it - the cursor should start to blink).

I have:

```
 private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       dataGridView1.Cells[3].ReadOnly = false;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the currentcell of the Datagridview and call BeginEdit

```
 private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    dataGridView1.Cells[3].ReadOnly = false;
    this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Cells[3];
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.beginedit.aspx

Comment: but readonly property dosen't seems to change after "=false;" it stays true. I have no idea why.

Comment: What is the setting for `DataGridViewEditMode` property? If that is set to `EditProgrammatically` it might be causing problems.

Comment: it was not set. I tried different configuration but it doesn't change anything. Trying to set my cell readonly false has no result.

Comment: Maybe try a different approach. Leave the Datagridview as editable and handle the `beginedit` event to cancel edits on cells that are not writable. That way, all cells should have `Readonly` set to false from the begining, but they wouldn't be actually editable.

Comment: I have changed Readonly property of dataGridView1 to true, but Each row to true. Now it works perfect.

Answer (score 2):

dataGridView1 ReadOnly property should be set to false.
each row ReadOnly property should be set to true.
then you can set the cell ReadOnly to true when required.

```
//setting each row

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    row.ReadOnly = true;
                }

//setting on cell

    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3];
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ReadOnly = false;                
    dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
```

Comment: To selectively change the ReadOnly property of a few cells, it seems like DataGridView.ReadOnly should be the same as DataGridViewCell.ReadOnly, and DataGridViewColumn or DataGridViewRow has to be the opposite. I got come cells to be made editable by having DataGridView.ReadOnly=false, All DatagridColumns.ReadOnly = true and DataGridViewCell.ReadOnly=false